# C# string interpolation weird characters added after replaced tokens

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I am not sure if this is something that I am doing but I am seeing some weird issues with interpolated strings. Here is an example

```
Trace.WriteLine($"Raising event {e.EventName} for document {e.DocumentId}", "Info");
```

In above case `e.EventName = DOCUMENT_CREATE` and `e.DocumentId = 111679`

so the result should be like following

```
Raising event DOCUMENT_CREATE for document 111679
```

but it is printing like

```
Raising event DOCUMENT_CREATE� for document 111679
```

Same is the case in some other places where I am using string interpolation. What could be causing it?

Another piece of info, client have installed .net 4.6.1 RC. Is there a bug in .net 4.6.1 RC?

Comment: It's probably an encoding issue, I'd guess.  What encoding are you using for the source, i.e. wherever `e.EventName` comes from?

Comment: And how does it compare with a non-interpolated version?

Comment: Encoding is same at source and destination. `e.EventName` is enum value

Comment: By "wired" do you mean "weird"?

Comment: Have you tried switching to `string.Format` or string concatenation to see if you get the same thing?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon thanks :)

Comment: @Mayank, can you observe the string in binary? If you receive the string from anohter location, it might be null-terminated. The last character might be a '\0'

Comment: @MethodMan the `$` is a new feature to do string interpolation

Comment: I just noticed that when I was reading the `interpolation` tag.. I wonder why @Mayank can't just write to a trace log and use the `string.Format` method

Comment: @MethodMan it's not about `Trace` logging at all. I am using string interpolation a lot of places in the code, involving some database query construction which is causing a havoc.

Comment: @PeterM I am testing, will keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

Well it was related to string interpolation but not entirely. We process our assemblies through SmartAssembly, and smart assembly messed up the interpolated strings by changing the encoding. SmartAssembly doesn't do that for non interpolated strings.